# Make my upload folder non-executable

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, folder-permissions

I've made an upload form on my site and was wondering if it's possible to make the upload folder and any file that gets up loaded non-executable?

I have taken other precautions like sanitizing anything that gets uploaded but I'd love to know if its possible to make my uploads folder and its contents non-executable

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -x` sets the file/folder non-executable. You can apply chmod in PHP to each file after upload.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: cool thanks. will files that have been uploaded after i chmod -x be non-executable?

Comment: @user1425394 No, you need to chmod -x that files after uploading. But probably the files wouldn't upload with executable permissions anyway.